# Can I search C# code to find non-logged exceptions?

Tags: c#, search, exception

We have a general-purpose logging class in our web site, but it wasn't used for all exceptions, making some debugging in production difficult. I want to search the code, identify exception blocks, and report if "Log.Write" doesn't appear in the block anywhere? I have no idea how to start - using the VS multiple file search isn't working. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: Debugging in production? Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn879356.aspx) for an idea.

Comment: So you have some try/catch blocks that are swallowing exceptions without properly handling/reporting on them?  What's not working about the multiple file search?  Seems ideal - just search for a catch and review it and move on - unless you have a huge number of try/catch blocks, which likely means an anti-pattern.

Comment: Eh, we have the right amount of exceptions, it's just a big app. I don't want to manually review them all. I'm just looking for more powerful code-searching tools, hopefully without resorting to perl.

Comment: Use code analysis with a custom rule?

Comment: Seconding earlier comment - don't just make sure you add logging to every try/catch. See if you can remove as many of them as possible. For example, if you call a service and the service calls a class and the class calls a stored procedure, you wouldn't want try/catch everywhere. If something blows up let it blow up and catch exceptions at the boundaries. Most of the time you don't need to catch exceptions, just places where you want to handle the error more gracefully or sometimes add some useful context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be an exact match, but if you're looking for code that's catching exceptions and just eating them or following some other bad practices this might be what you need.

I wrote the class below containing the most common bad habits I encounter with exceptions. Then I started looking for a way to flag the bad code. (The last method is okay - I wanted to make sure it wouldn't get flagged.)

What I found is this Visual Studio extension: [Exception Analyzer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ef473182-2549-439c-9bf9-8582e4bdcebe).

I'm running Visual Studio 2015. The extension itself seemed to throw a few exceptions, but it still gave me useful compile warnings when methods mishandle exceptions. (I can disable the errors and keep using this, so that's fine.) I've pasted the warnings as comments in the code below.

Conclusion - this is awesome. Three out of three, 100%. I've done this manually at times, and other times I've resolved to do it but it was never a priority. Thanks for the question. It led me to something I can really use.

```
public class Class1
{
    public void EatException()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blarg");
        }
        catch
        { 
            //Catching everything considered harmful!
            //Are you not curious at all about exception type?
        }
    }

    public void LogExceptionWithoutRethrowing()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blarg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
            //Exit point '}' swallows an exception!
            //Consider throwing an exception instead.   

            //(Logging without rethrowing isn't necessarily bad,
            //but I want to know where it's happening.)
        }
    }

    public void LogExceptionAndRethrowBadly()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blarg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
            throw ex;
            //Rethrowing exception is possibly intended.

            //(Weird message, but that's fine. It still caught the
            //"throw ex" which wipes out the stacktrace.)
        }
    }

    public void LogExceptionAndRethrow()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Blarg");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException(ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, I don't believe in catching, logging, and rethrowing exceptions in every method of every class, as in the last method above. In fact I hardly ever do it. I mostly use Windsor interceptors.
But of the purpose of finding a way to track down mishandled exceptions I wanted to include an "okay" method to make sure it wouldn't get flagged.

Comment: Thank you for actually answering. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.